# How to build activiti services in activiti-exploer

Tags: activiti

I new bine with activiti workflow!
I create new project activiti helloworld in esclip. 
Project with one file MyProcess.bpmn. It have one service, in service, I set class name: test.HelloWorldActiviti

**Class HelloWorldActiviti**

```
package test; 
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate;
public class HelloWorldActiviti implements JavaDelegate {
    public String abc;
    String tesst;
    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution arg0) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello world!!");

    }

}
```

How to run examlpe in activiti exploer?

Answer (score 0):

You should create new proccess with Eclipse process designer and add there Service taks at properties pane put class name of HelloWorldActiviti. Then you should deply process to Activit explorer, don't forget add jar with compiled class to lib folder of Activiti explorer.

Comment: Thank Paul!I run activiti